# SQL Server - Granting same IDs to "matching" Variables IDs

Tags: sql-server, matching, identifier

this title may sounds a bit confusing at the beginning but I hope my example clarifies my intentions.

```
ID1      ID2   uniqueidentifier

A14      A21
A14      A55
A21      A14
A21      A55
A55      A14
A55      A21
...
A123     A22
A22      A123
...
```

Behind the IDs there a company names that I matched based on some criteria.
Basically the displayed example means, that ID 'A14' matched with 'A21', but also the other way around (of course). And that there is a third company name that matched the criteria.

I can´t group them by company name, as the names are sometimes written differently as followed:

- The Example Company Corp.

- Example Company Corp.

Basically the first 6 rows would have the same identifier. And the other two as well.
The uniqueidentifier will be a new one at this point, as I want to update this table with NEWID().

The question is: How I can assign uniqueidentifiers (NEWID() ) so that it looks like the output

Any suggestions for my problem?

I would be very happy for any kind of help, as this is a problem I´ve been thinking about for a long time.

EDIT: The expected output looks like this:

```
ID1      ID2   uniqueidentifier

A14      A21   XXER-WQEE-...
A14      A55   XXER-WQEE-...
A21      A14   XXER-WQEE-...
A21      A55   XXER-WQEE-...
A55      A14   XXER-WQEE-...
A55      A21   XXER-WQEE-...
...
A123     A22   IOKK-Q23A-...
A22      A123  IOKK-Q23A-...
...
```

Thanks
MG

Comment: Can you please show expected output

Comment: where does that uniqueidentifier come from?

Comment: I would update the table at this moment with 'NEWID()'

Comment: @mgruber:please look here to improve the question ..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The things I´ve tried didn´t even closely lead to the wanted solution. Thats why I didn´t post it, so I can get new ideas & help from unbiased users

Comment: @mgruber:Ask here being ,the question is not clear

Comment: @mgruber This is not clear. Show sample data and expected result please.

Comment: The question is: How I can assign uniqueidentifiers (NEWID() ) so that it looks like the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one should give the result you want. Sorry, it's a bit messy. Ask questions if you need an explanation.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID1 varchar(100), ID2 varchar(100), uniqueid uniqueidentifier)

INSERT @Table1
    ( ID1, ID2, uniqueid )
VALUES
    ( '1',  '2',  NULL  ),
    ( '2',  '1',  NULL  ),
    ( '2',  '3',  NULL  ),
    ( '3',  '2',  NULL  ),
    ( '1',  '3',  NULL  ),
    ( '3',  '1',  NULL  ),
    ( '4',  '5',  NULL  ),
    ( '5',  '4',  NULL  )

DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @NewID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

DECLARE @ID2 TABLE (ID2 varchar(100))

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Table1 WHERE uniqueid IS NULL)
BEGIN

SET @NewID = NEWID()

SELECT @tmp = ID1
FROM @Table1
WHERE uniqueid IS NULL

DELETE @ID2

UPDATE @Table1 
SET uniqueid = @NewID
OUTPUT Inserted.ID2
INTO @ID2
WHERE ID1 = @tmp

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @ID2 JOIN @Table1 ON [@Table1].ID1 = [@ID2].ID2 WHERE [@Table1].uniqueid IS NULL)
BEGIN

    UPDATE t1 
    SET uniqueid = @NewID
    OUTPUT Inserted.ID2
    INTO @ID2
    FROM @Table1 t1
    JOIN @ID2 id2 ON t1.ID1 = id2.ID2

END


END

SELECT * FROM @Table1
```

Comment: This was excactly what I was looking for! Thumbs UP!!

Comment: Hi Valera! I added another answer to this question about changed requirements of my first question. I hope you can help me with that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

The situation changed and I need the code adapted. 
It occurs that some of the IDs already have an uniqueidentifier.

The code posted above (by @Valera Soroka) only considers IDs where the uniqueidentifier is NULL. That means that it would grant new uniqueidentifiers for line 3-6 in the example, if line 1-2 already have an uniqueidentifier. The code needs to look for IDs with uniqueidentifier first.

Additionally I want to add the country, so the loop gets more performant, as the loop only goes through IDs with the same country. So the country needs the be implemented in the code.

So the actual situation looks like this:

```
ID1      ID2   Country(ID1)  uniqueidentifier

A14      A21      USA        XXER-WQEE-...
A14      A55      USA        XXER-WQEE-...
A21      A14      USA
A21      A55      USA
A55      A14      USA
A55      A21      USA
...
A123     A22   Canada
A22      A123  Canada
...
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
ID1      ID2   Country(ID1)  uniqueidentifier

A14      A21      USA        XXER-WQEE-...
A14      A55      USA        XXER-WQEE-...
A21      A14      USA        XXER-WQEE-...
A21      A55      USA        XXER-WQEE-...
A55      A14      USA        XXER-WQEE-...
A55      A21      USA        XXER-WQEE-...
...
A123     A22   Canada        IOKK-Q23A-...
A22      A123  Canada        IOKK-Q23A-...
...
```

(I just took the same IDs as above, the IDs could be any IDs)

Thanks a lot for your help!
MG